# How to avoid underflow pitfalls when iterating manually?

Tags: rust

The code below would panic because `j` is typed as `usize`.

```
fn foo(vec: &Vec<i32>) {
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut j = vec.len() - 1;
    while i < j {
        while i < j && !some_condition(vec[i]) {
            i += 1;
        }
        while i < j && !some_condition(vec[j]) {
            j -= 1;
        }
        if i < j {
            vec.swap(i, j);
            i += 1;
            j -= 1;
        }
    }
}

foo(&vec![]);
```

Most of the time iterator helps to avoid such issues. But when we have to manually iterate with indexes we really need to be careful. I could check the size of `vec` ahead to avoid panic. But the real problem here is I tend to think the program would work as expected even without empty check until a corner case bites me. So I wonder if there is any idiomatic way to do this kind of things in Rust.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You answered your own question, without more context it's hard to provide a better answer.

Comment: the comment *"// If vec is empty, we still enter the loop due to underflow"* is misleading since the panic occurs just before, while computing `vec.len() - 1`.

Comment: You're right. I've messed things up before.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at `saturating_sub` or `checked_sub`:

```rust
fn foo(vec: &Vec<i32>) {
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut j = vec.len().saturating_sub(1); 
    while i < j {
        // Some other logic
        i += 1;
        // EITHER
        j.saturating_sub(1); // avoid getting below 0
        //OR
        j = j.checked_sub(1).expect("usize underflow");
    }
}

foo(&vec![]);
```

If you want some more complex handling instead of `.expect()` you can use:

```rust
j = j.checked_sub(1).ok_or_else(|| some_your_error_creator())?;
```

which seems more idiomatic, but will require some additional work with error-handling.

Comment: The inner `saturating_sub`/`checked_sub` wouldn't be needed, as `j` is greater than `i`/`0` :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd just do as you suggest `vec.is_empty()` and then `return`, to keep the logic clear.

If you don't want that, then instead you can perform a saturating subtraction using [`saturating_sub()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.saturating_sub). If the subtraction would result in an underflow then it would remain at `0`.

```rust
// let mut j = vec.len() - 1;
let mut j = vec.len().saturating_sub(1);
```